# Why the new variables formed by Almon distributed lag model are still highly correlated?

Tags: time-series, multicollinearity, lags

I just got started with the Almon distributed lag model. This is good [reference](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2017/01/explaining-almon-distributed-lag-model.html) I found that was very helpful and I basically followed the same methodology to create  the "transformed" new variables.

My understanding of the reasons to use Almon distributed lag model is to reduce the multicollinearity generated by simply shifting the time series itself (i.e. $X_t$ can be highly correlated with $X_{t-1}$). However, I found the transformed variables are also highly correlated, even more than the shifted time series themselves. I am curious whether it is because I did something wrong or it is how it works, meaning the transformed new varaibles ($Z_0$, $Z_1$, $Z_2$) in the reference blog post.

I have my demo dataset and calculation in a spreadsheet shared [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15aiZ5AGASYfcB78Ke-oVxFBpvNF7sn9U/view?usp=sharing) on a Google Drive. The data is daily and I created lags by week (7 days). The max lag is 10 weeks. I found that the maximum correlation between pairs of lagged series is about 0.4 ~ 0.5. However, when I used the formula below to create the z-variables and transform the 11 variables into three ( I am using a polynomial distribution model with power of 2) variables (a0, a1, a2 in the spreadsheet),

$Z_{0t} = (X_t + X_{t-1} +  X_{t-2} + ......+  X_{t-n})$

$Z_{1t} = (X_{t-1} + 2X_{t-2} + .... + nX_{t-n})$

$Z_{2t} =  (X_{t-1} + 4X_{t-2} + 9X_{t-3} +...... + n^2X_{t-n})$

the correlation coefficients were all above 0.9. When we use the new variables in a linear regression, don't we still need to deal with the multicollinearity? 
So I am wondering if I did something fundamentally wrong or I misunderstand the methodology.

Could someone advise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are all those t's supposed to be subscripts? You can use LaTeX here. That might make it at least a little clearer.

Comment: @PeterFlom, Thank you for pointing this out. Just made edits to the question post and hope this made it clearer.